# Feature gate custom module from sites/all in Drupal 7 multisite

Tags: multi-sites

I am working on a legacy drupal 7 multisite and want to see if I can "feature gate" a module in sites/all/custom instead of loading it per individual site. For example, lets say I have 5 sites in my Multi site:

SiteA

SiteB

SiteC

SiteD

SiteE

right now a custom module lets call my_custom_module resides in the modules/custom dir of Sites A-D but not E. For reasons I won't go into, the powers that be want to move my_custom_module out of the other sites and into sites/all/modules/custom and only have it work, again, on Sites A-D but not E. I have thought about doing some fancy feature gating by setting a variable called use-my-custom-module in A-D but not E and then checking for it via:

```
if(variable_get('use-my-custom-module', FALSE) === TRUE) {
  // use some function
}
```

but that seems an awfully un Drupal and clunky way of doing things. Is there a more Drupally and non clunky way of getting at this? Or should I tell Powers That Be not to try this. Again, "Reason not the need..." here, its a weird rabbit hole to go down. I just want to back up my assumed "no" answer.

Comment: I'm probably missing something important, but assuming the databases are separate, can't you just not enable the module on site E if you don't need it?

Comment: We tried a hook_n to disable per site but for some reason its still being enabled. Also I've been informed that core is hacked so I have  to dig a bit deeper.